# Import urlfetch doesn't work on Jython Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jython, urlfetch

I'm using Jython on Google App Engine, but I can't get 'import urlfetch' to work. Other imports like 'import sys' and 'import zlib' work, but not 'import urlfetch'. I get a 500 Server Error. What am I doing wrong?

The error messages in my dashboard log are:

1) `javax.servlet.ServletContext log: debug:    Callable object not in cache`

2) Error for `/java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

3) Nested in `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:java.security.AccessControlException:access` denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)

4) Uncaught exception from servlet

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I also tried switching threadsafe to both false and true, but neither seems to have any effect (I saw somewhere that there might be a problem with jython and threadsafe=TRUE).

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: I think that is because there already is a module called urlfetch try import URLfetch

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work

Comment: My question is.. why running Jython when GAE supports pure Python and pure Java..?

Comment: How did you get Jython to work on App Engine? Any references? We have been searching.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
```

As from this:

> You can use the Python standard libraries urllib, urllib2 or httplib to make HTTP requests. When running in App Engine, these libraries perform HTTP requests using App Engine's URL fetch service, which runs on Google's scalable HTTP request infrastructure.

I read that it's not the "normal" urlfetch in use in GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview

Comment: Thanks, yes I have been using 'from google.appengine.api import urlfetch', but it doesn't work. When I try to import urlfetch, urllib, or urllib2, I get errors. Could this be something on Google's side? Are they not allowing jython to use functions that try to make HTTP requests?